strange `re.sub` behaviour if the string include `\n` symbol
I am trying to extract a part of string prior to substring:
import re

s = "ab\nc"
print(re.sub(r"(.*)b.*", r"\1", s)) # a\nc

I would expect to get a, but I am getting a\nc.
Why is it?

"In my view the pattern definitely can not match anything after b" - Then why do you expect that it does?

The (?s) is an inline modifier that enables the "dot-all" mode. In this mode, the dot matches all characters, including the newlines (e.g., \n). Without (?s), the dot does not match newlines.
print(re.sub(r"(?s)(.*)b.*", r"\1", 'ab\nc'))



Other patterns to use are:
print(re.sub(r"(.*)b[\s\S]*", r"\1", 'ab\nc'))
print(re.sub(r"(.*)b[\w\W]*", r"\1", 'ab\nc'))
print(re.sub(r"(.*)b[\d\D]*", r"\1", 'ab\nc'))


which outputs: a.

You might have forgotten to add r:
print(re.sub(r"(.*)b.*", r"\1", r'ab\nc'))


Another way to get a is to use positive lookahead, assuming \n is NOT a new line:
import re
regex = r'^[^\r\n]*(?=b.*$)'
st = r'ab\nc'

print(re.findall(regex, st))


which outputs:
['a']


@Andrey What's your actual input? Is that it: ab\nc?

I can find some other ways to do the task. My question is - why the way desrcribed doesn't work

@Andrey because you forgot to add r: print(re.sub(r"(.*)b.*", r"\1", r'ab\nc'))

I actually have 'ab\nc' in string variable and can not add r there. Will update the example

@Andrey Okay, try: print(re.sub(r"(.*)b[\s\S]*", r"\1", 'ab\nc')) instead.

thanks, can you please add @Mark's comment in the answer to make it clearer?

It's already there: print(re.sub(r"(?s)(.*)b.*", r"\1", 'ab\nc')) adding (?s) flag is the same.

I mean that part: . doesn't match a new line. It actually is an answer
